# java.lang.StackOverflowError when running class as TestNG Test in Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

This is a demo project, implementation is done using Page Object Pattern and Data driven framework.

Below inheritance, constructor concepts are used.

The `config.prpoerties` file has username, password, url and browser.

### Base Class

```
package com.crm.qa.base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

import com.crm.qa.utilities.TestUtil;

public class TestBase {
    
    public static Properties prop;
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public TestBase() {
    
        //import variables from Config.properties file
        try {
            prop=new Properties();
    
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/com/crm/qa/configuration/config.properties");
    
                prop.load(fis);         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
    
    public static void  initialization()
    {
        String browser= prop.getProperty("browser");
        
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./Drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
            firefoxOptions.setCapability("marionette", true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);     
        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
    
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("baseURL"));
    }               
}
```

### Login Page Object Class

```
package com.crm.qa.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;

public class LoginPageCRM extends TestBase {
    
    
    //PageFactory
    @FindBy(name="username")
    WebElement username;
    
    
    @FindBy(name="password")
    WebElement password;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit']")
    WebElement loginBtn;    
    
    @FindBy(xpath= "//a[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")
    WebElement signUP;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//img[contains(@class,'img-responsive')]")
    WebElement crmLogo;
    
    //to initialize page objects
    
    public LoginPageCRM()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class );
    }
    
    
    //Actions
    //1. verify title of page
    public String validateLoginPageTitle()
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
        
    }
    
    //2. Validate crm image
    public boolean validateCRMLogo()
    {
        return crmLogo.isDisplayed();
    }
    
    //3. Login
    public HomePageCRM login(String uname, String pwd)  
    {
        username.sendKeys(uname);
        password.sendKeys(pwd);
        loginBtn.click();
        
        return new HomePageCRM();
    }

}
```

<------------------------------------LoginTest Class------------------------------------->

```
package com.crm.qa.testcases;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.crm.qa.base.TestBase;
import com.crm.qa.pages.HomePageCRM;
import com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPageCRM;


public class LoginTest extends TestBase{
    
    public LoginTest()
    {
        super(); 
    }
    
    LoginPageCRM loginPage;
    public HomePageCRM homePageCRM;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUP()
    {
    initialization();
    loginPage=new LoginPageCRM();
    }
    
    
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void LoginPageTitleTest()
    {
        String pageTitle= loginPage.validateLoginPageTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(pageTitle,"CRMPRO  - CRM software for customer relationship management, sales, and support.");
        
    }
    
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void CRMLogoTest()
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(loginPage.validateCRMLogo(), true);
    }
    
    @Test(priority=3)
    public  void loginPageTest()
    {
        homePageCRM= loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
    }
    
    
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown()
    {
    driver.quit();      
    }

}
```

Now when I run the LoginTest class as TestNG Test, I get error in console as below-->

```
com.crm.qa.testcases.LoginTest#setUP


Exception

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamOpFlag.fromCharacteristics(StreamOpFlag.java:733)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(StreamSupport.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5446)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5427)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.methodToString(Class.java:3579)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3508)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:64)
    at com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPageCRM.<init>(LoginPageCRM.java:33)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:64)
    at com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPageCRM.<init>(LoginPageCRM.java:33)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:64)
    at com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPageCRM.<init>(LoginPageCRM.java:33)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor9.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)

 

 ........
```

My Eclipse verion :
Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)
Build id: 20210312-0638

eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\JACOB\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\JACOB\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.19.0.20210311-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-15.0.1/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounterd this bug once. How to fix it, change

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class );
```

to

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```

Comment: Explanation to why the current code `PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class)` fails -> `initElements` tries to create a object of `LoginPageCRM` by invoking it's constructor. As the constructor of `LoginPageCRM` contains `PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class)`. So this process is repeated infinite times leading to Stackoverflow error. This is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: So PageFactory.initElements(driver, this) will return object of the current class?

Answer (score 0):

`PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class)` is causing the `StackOverflowError` because `initElements` tries to create a object of `LoginPageCRM` by invoking it's constructor. And as the constructor of `LoginPageCRM` contains `PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class)`, this process is repeated infinite times leading to `StackOverflowError`. This is the root cause of the issue.

Since I am not much familiar with selenium, I assume @**lucasnguyen17**'s answer explains how to fix it. But I would suggest a few changes before passing `this` to that method within a constructor.

---

**NOTE: The below mentioned issue might NOT cause an issue in your case as there are no other operations with `this` inside the constructor. But the below can be followed as a general guideline/best-practice**

---

An object is considered not properly constructed, if the `this` reference "escapes" during construction. i.e the object is said to be properly constructed only if the constructor is fully executed. If you fix your code as below, you are passing a **not properly constructed object** to the `initElements` method. This could be thought as analogous to renting a house to someone before the construction is even completed. Hence this is a wrong practice and should **NOT** be done as it could lead to unexpected results as you may not know what the method you are calling, is going to do with the object you pass.

```java
public LoginPageCRM()
{
    // The object is not fully constructed at this point
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

So I would suggest the below refactor:

In `LoginPageCRM` just create a default constructor without any code within it. (Java would actually create one, if there are no other constructors in the class). Then create a method that would do the `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)`:

```java
public LoginPageCRM()
{
}

public void init() {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

Then in the `LoginTest` class, after constructing the `LoginPageCRM` object, invoke the new `init` method, so that you can ensure that you are passing a properly constructed object.

```java
@BeforeTest
public void setUP() {
    initialization();
    loginPage = new LoginPageCRM();
    loginPage.init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gautham M, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
public LoginPageCRM()
{
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageCRM.class );
}
    

This line in your page class constructor in turn call below internal PageFactory method to instantiate LoginPageCRM class which again call this LoginPageCRM constructor. It continue till stack overflows.

  **T page = instantiatePage(driver, pageClassToProxy);**


        public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, Class<T> pageClassToProxy) {
        T page = instantiatePage(driver, pageClassToProxy);
        initElements(driver, page);
        return page;
      }
```